# Search more then one MySql table in Mysql Database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search, html-table

I have a database have 20 tables I want to search all of these I got stuck that how can I search this and solve this query help is very appreciated. Like:

> 1. table1
> 2. table2
> 3. table3
> 4. table4

and so one. This is my script.

```
<?php  
                 if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
                 {  
                      $condition = '';  
                      //$query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);
                      $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);

                      foreach($query as $text)  
                      {  
                           $condition .= "`title`  LIKE +'%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";  
                      }  
                      $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);  
                      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM countries2 WHERE " . $condition;  
                      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);  
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
                      {  
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                           {  
                                echo '<tr><td>'.$row["title"].'</td></tr>';  
                           }  
                      }  
                      else  
                      {  
                           echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';  
                      }  
                 }  
                 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `countries`,`countries2`   WHERE " . $condition;
```

i have noticed that you are making a search directory or something like this.

you may use `FULLTEXT SEARCH` with operators and `Stemming` 
after this your query will look like this.
implement as per your requirement ;).

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE(col1,col2,clo3) AGAINST(."$search".) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```